# Given a triangle with sides $a, b, c$ prove that: $a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c)\le 3abc$

Tags: geometry, inequality, contest-math

Given a triangle with sides $a, b, c$ prove that: $a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c)\le 3abc$

I attempted to solve this question as follows:

$a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c)\le 3abc$

$a^2(b+c)+b^2(c+a)+c^2(a+b)-(a^3+b^3+c^3)\le 3abc$

$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)-2abc-3abc\le 3abc$

$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)-5abc\le 3abc$

$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\le 8abc$

And I got stuck here. Could you please explain to me how to finish it off?

Comment: The last equation $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\le 8abc$ must be $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\ge 8abc$. Just apply the AM-GM inequality, for example $a +b \ge 2 \sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: You have a wrong step! The right inequality is $a^3+b^3+c^3\geq 3abc$ but you cannot use this inequality

Comment: As @NN2 pointed out, it is possible to continue from there, open the brackets and substract from the both sides, and then you can check for each bracket part of the left side (3 brackets with the $a,b,c$) for each case of inequalities, $a\leq b\leq c \quad a\leq c\leq b ...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a=y+z,b=x+z,c=x+y$ then we have to prove $$\sum 2z{(y+z)}^2\le 3(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \tag 1$$ Now note that $$\sum (2x{(z+y)}^2-8xyz)=\sum 2x{(y-z)}^2$$ and $$(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)-8zxy=\sum z{(x-y)}^2$$ therfore  after subtracting $24xyz$ from both sides of $(1)$ it remains to rpove $$\sum z{(x-y)}^2\ge 0$$ which is true

Note that one could actually multiply out inequality $(1)$ to get $$x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y)\ge 6xyz$$ which is true by AM_GM but i felt writing it as an SOS is more nice

Comment: Hello, could you please explain to me why you substituted $a=y+z$ etc.?

Comment: @MichaelBlane its the Ravi's substituition because by triangle inequality $x,y,z>0$

Comment: @MichaelBlane as it is triangle we could start by subbing $2x=c+b-a,so on$ which yeilds $$a=x+y,b=y+z,etc$$

Answer (score 1):

It is just Schur’s $^{[1]}$ Inequality of degree 3. You can search the web and read about it. It is pretty well known and someone named Aritra12 posted a handout on it recently on Aops.